# The problem occurs when update my plug-in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

> Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in /www/wwwroot//wp-includes/plugin.php(493) : > runtime-created function on line 1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file or folder does not exists.
Check permissions on that folder.

Comment: but plugin.php do existed in my path

Comment: Did you check folder permissions?

Comment: no,i dont know how to do that

Comment: You need an FTP file manager like filezilla to access to server files or alternatively from your hosting CPanel

Comment: "The server sent back a non-routable address"

Comment: it is empty.but i know my files are on sever

Comment: Try install plugin files manually